# How can I display recent tweets from a group of users in ASP.Net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I'm developing a Asp.Net website and I need to display the four most recent tweets from a group of users (around ten) that will be set in the admin area of the website. I know twitter has an API, but I don't know where to start. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [WCF REST Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx) doc. Here's a sample from the page:

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient("http://twitter.com/statuses/");
http.TransportSettings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("{username}", "{password}");
HttpResponseMessage resp = http.Get("friends_timeline.xml");
resp.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();
ProcessStatuses(resp.Content.ReadAsStream());
```

Also download the kit from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wrapper-type API called Yedda that's ridiculously easy to use.  I got it working in just a few minutes, and it's pretty self-explanatory.

http://devblog.yedda.com/index.php/twitter-c-library/

Comment: Now that I look at it more closely, it may not be clear how to do exactly what you're trying to do.  You may need to try a few different things, and maybe create a new Twitter user that follows these accounts, in order to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Several .NET Libraries that interface with the Twitter API

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#csharp